# Prime and maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Do the set $\{ p(x,y): P(a,b)=0\}$ is a maximal( or prime)  ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. If so what will be its principal ideal form representation.(Since all ideals are principal).

I feel the ideal is maximal as viewing $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ as a $R[x]$ and $\{ p(x,y): P(a,b)=0\}$ as a $<x-\alpha>$, (where, $\alpha$ corresponds to (a,b))

Comment: Usually, we consider $p$ and $P$ to be different. Do you mean $\{p(x, y): p(a, b) = 0\}$?

Comment: yup, both are denoting same polynomial

Comment: You are heavily mistaken if you think that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ has only principal ideals. Consider for example $(x,y)$, this is not a principal ideal.

Comment: It is not true that all ideals are principal. Indeed this ideal is generated by $x-a,y-b$ and cannot be generated by only one polynomial.

Comment: So, is my ideal prime or maximal. How to conclude that.

Comment: yup, need not be principal. if R=F some field, then we can guarantee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** To prove that your ideal is maximal, apply the first isomorphism theorem to $P\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]\mapsto P(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}$.

If you want to go further, you can prove that your ideal is $(x-a,y-b)$ (use generalized long division of polynomials carefully), and that it is **NOT** a principal ideal (if so, a generator is a common divisor of $x-a$ and $y-b$, so...)

Comment: The set, $\{p(x): p(a)=0\} $ will this be maximal ideal in any $R[x]$.

Comment: No. Take $a=0$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}$.